# Hadoop -mkdir : - Could not create the Java Virtual Machine

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have configured the Hadoop 1.0.4 and started the following without any issue:

```
1. $ start-dfs.sh : -Works fine

2. $ start-mapred.sh : - Work fine

3. $ jps  (Output is below)
```

**Out put:**

```
rahul@rahul-Inspiron-N4010:/usr/local/hadoop-1.0.4/bin$ jps

6964 DataNode

7147 SecondaryNameNode

6808 NameNode

7836 Jps

7254 JobTracker

7418 TaskTracker
```

**But facing issue:** While issuing command

```
rahul@rahul-Inspiron-N4010:/usr/local/hadoop-1.0.4/bin$ hadoop -mkdir /user
```

Getting following error

```
Unrecognized option: -mkdir
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I applied the patch : **HDFS-1943.patch** but not use full

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should be: `hdfs dfs -mkdir /user`

Consult documentation at http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/file_system_shell.html

Comment: Thanks i am able to resolve the problem......I am new to hadoop so just struggling a bit with inital setup

Answer (score 4):

fs option is missing

`hadoop fs -mkdir /user`

Comment: Thanks i am able to resolve the problem......I am new to hadoop so just struggling a bit with inital setup